# hMailServer not delivering Google Apps mail

Tags: routes, google-apps, mail-server, hmail-server, gmail-pop

i am using **hMailServer** of version **hMailServer-5.4-B1944** on **windows 7**. My **www.xyz.com.np** domain mail is hosted on gmail. I have forwarded or set up catch all email to **mail@xyz.com.np** . I have enabled **fowarding and POP/IMAP** from the email account part.

I created an local domain ***xyz.com.np*** on **hMailServer**. Created ***mail@xyz.com.np*** under that domain. On external accounts tab, i defined

```
name MY NAME,
enabled YES ,
server address pop.gmail.com
port 995
use SSL YES
username mail@xyz.com.np (of the gmail)
password ********** (of the gmail)
minutes between download 3
Deliver to receipients in MIME headers YES
Retrieve date from Received header YES
Do not Delete Messages YES
```

Saved and clicked on Download Now.
I can login/send and receive local emails from/to hmailserver from both outlook and Round Cube mail. But no emails pulled from gmail.

My Firewalls are OFF. I can telnet or get blank at **telnet pop.gmail.com 995**
No Email messages are downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yuppy.... got my answer

there was a minor mistake..

**Signing in using application-specific passwords**

http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185833

I was using google mail apps password..

```
name MY NAME
enabled YES 
server address pop.gmail.com
port 995
use SSL YES
username mail@xyz.com.np (of the gmail)
password ********** (of the gmail)
minutes between download 3
Deliver to receipients in MIME headers YES
Retrieve date from Received header YES
Do not Delete Messages YES
```

Instead of **password of the gmail** use the **application-specific passwords**
http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185833 =>> click the link for Singing up for Application specific password

Comment: If the solution resolved your issue, please mark it as Resolved!